# How do I enter data in a program to count the entered characters?

Tags: c

I wrote two programs in C to count characters and print the value.

One uses the while loop and the other uses for. No errors are reported while compiling, but neither print anything.

Here's the code using *while*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters and input using while */
main()
{
    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
        ++nc;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

And here's the code using *for*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* count characters and input using for */
main()
{
    long nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

Both compile and run.

When I type input and hit enter, a blank newline prints. When I hit enter without inputting anything, again a blank newline prints. I think it should at least print zero.

Comment: A newline is not an EOF.

Comment: I know what a newline is, and I know what the EOF is (on my machine EOF = -1). I was stating that when ever anything is input into the program, only a newline appears, and the program doesn't print the character count like I want it to.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If you haven't hit Ctrl+D or Ctrl+Z, you haven't finished executing your program.

Comment: Which operating system/shell are you using? The problem is that EOF character is tricky for user input. It's definitely not corresponding to the Enter key. On Windows, it's most likely to correspond to CTRL+Z (although, I don't guarantee it). If you want the while loop to stop when you hit enter, you need to compare the getchar() return value to CR/LF (ASCII codes 13/10).

Comment: Ctrl+D did it, thanks everyone. And wow this is the first time I've used stackoverflow, you guys sure respond quick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to terminate the input to your program (i.e. trigger the EOF test).

You can do this on most unix terminals with Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z at the start of a new line on most windows command windows.

Alternately you can redirect stdin from a file, e.g.:

```
myprogram < test.txt
```

Also, you should give main a return type; implicit `int` is deprecated.

```
int main(void)
```

Comment: Thanks Charles. I was hitting Ctrl-Z when it was Ctrl-D. Everything is working now :).

And if implicit int is deprecated, should I also be doing     return 0;?

Comment: @MW2000: You get an implicit `return 0;` if you don't have one in main but personally I think it's better to make it explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Your programs will only output after seeing an end of file (EOF). Generate this on UNIX with CTRL-D or on Windows with CTRL-Z.

Answer (score 1):

You wait for an EOF character (end of file) here. This will only happen in two scenarios:

- The user presses Ctrl+Break (seems to work on Windows here, but I wouldn't count on this).
- The user enters a EOF character (can be done with Ctrl+Z for example).

A better way to do this would be to check for a newline instead.

Answer (score 1):

for your program to work correctly. after you press the <kbd>enter</kbd> key, u have to ensure that uyou terminate your loop, so that the program flos correctly. this is done by typing the <kbd>ctrl+Z</kbd> from your keyboard. these are the keys that correspond to the EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Pressing Enter on your keyboard, adds the character `\n` to your input.  In order to and the program and have it print out the number of characters you would need to add an 'End of File' (EOF) character.

In order to inject an EOF character, you should press `CTRL-D` in Unix or `CTRL-Z` on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that newline is a normal character, and not an EOF indicator? EOF would be Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z on most popular OSes.