# Character Counting in C

Tags: c

In the program below, I'm trying to count the characters in a line

```
#include <stdio.h>
    /* count characters in input; 1st version */

int main()
{
    double nc;

    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

But the line
`printf("%.0f\n", nc)`
is not getting executed
The result is like:

```
hello     
world
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't actually compile this program successfully, and what you're executing is a previously-compiled version of a different program that prints "hello world".

Comment: press `CTRL+Z` or `CRTL+D` and enter.

Comment: @AndyLester The OP means that s/he entered that on the terminal, but didn't get back the response s/he was expecting (a count of characters) -- not that the program output "hello\nworld" out of the blue.

Comment: There seems to be a similar question (with almost exactly the same code) on here that has already been answered.. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304133/simple-c-program-to-count-character-help-please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304133/simple-c-program-to-count-character-help-please)

Comment: @AndyLester Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry for the confusion. :P

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I tried CRTL+D, and I did get result like hello\n6D, and the program stopped. Why is that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple C program to Count Character - Help please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304133/simple-c-program-to-count-character-help-please)

Comment: You must enter from the console code that represents the EOF. (Since not end unlike the case of input from a file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EOF` is only end of **file**, not end of line. See [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getchar.html). So when you hit enter, your program stays in that `for` loop. You can fix this one of two ways:

- Actually send your program `EOF` (`Ctrl-D` on most *nix-based systems), or
- check for a newline instead of `EOF`.

Try this:

```
  for (nc = 0; getchar() != '\n'; ++nc)
```

Note that your code will exit after the first newline you send.